# hide page in acrobat form if fields are not populated

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have a 6 page form in acrobat XI Pro and need to hide pages based on the value of a text box on page 2.

Page 1: Instructions
Page 2: A test sample form with a text box at the top that allows for values 1 - 5 for the number of test samples being submitted. Based on this value, this page is replicated through pages 3 - 6 to allow for additional sample submissions using the javascript below. If a user selects 1 sample to submit, the additional blank pages still remain. How can I hide the actual pages 3 - 6 if only 1 sample is being submitted?

I have a very basic understanding of javascript, so any help would be appreciated!

```
function updateTests()
{
var numTests = this.getField("numberTests");

if(numTests.value > 5){
this.getField("numberTests").value = "";
app.alert("Maximum number of tests allowed for this form is 5. If more are    needed, another form will be required. Please try again.");
}

numTests.value = (numTests && numTests.value >= 1) ? numTests.value : "";

this.getField("tests").value = numTests.value;
var pg2 = this.getField("pageCover2");
var pg3 = this.getField("pageCover3");
var pg4 = this.getField("pageCover4");
var pg5 = this.getField("pageCover5");

pg2.display = (numTests.value >= 2)? display.hidden : display.visible;
pg3.display = (numTests.value >= 3) ? display.hidden : display.visible;
pg4.display = (numTests.value >= 4) ? display.hidden : display.visible;
pg5.display = (numTests.value >= 5) ? display.hidden : display.visible;

this.getField("tests").value = numTests.value;
var pg2 = this.getField("pageCover2");
var pg3 = this.getField("pageCover3");
var pg4 = this.getField("pageCover4");
var pg5 = this.getField("pageCover5");

pg2.display = (numTests.value >= 2)? display.hidden : display.visible;
pg3.display = (numTests.value >= 3) ? display.hidden : display.visible;
pg4.display = (numTests.value >= 4) ? display.hidden : display.visible;
pg5.display = (numTests.value >= 5) ? display.hidden : display.visible;

var pgNum1 = this.getField("page1");
var pgNum2 = this.getField("page2");
var pgNum3 = this.getField("page3");
var pgNum4 = this.getField("page4");
var pgNum5 = this.getField("page5");

pgNum1.value = "Page 1 of " + numTests.value;
pgNum2.value = "Page 2 of " + numTests.value;
pgNum3.value = "Page 3 of " + numTests.value;
pgNum4.value = "Page 4 of " + numTests.value;
pgNum5.value = "Page 5 of " + numTests.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

And the whole shebang should work with Reader, I presume?

Have a closer look at the Acrobat JavaScript documentation (which is part of the Acrobat SDK, downloadable from the Adobe website).

You will find that it would be possible to show/hide pages, but only if they are made Templates, and if you are using Acrobat.

For something working with Reader XI or newer, you would do it the other way round; you start with the base page, and have the following page as a hidden Template. Then you evaluate the number of test samples and spawn that page the according number of times (that would also make the maximum number of test samples less strict).